# Salesforce lookups not displaying results

Tags: custom-object, lookup

When creating a new record for a custom object on the standard page layouts the results of the lookup do not start showing up until the user enters 3 letters. The problem is the records that are being looked up are only 2 letters long so no results show up.

[image]

You have to click the search button and then,
[image]

The record shows up. Is there any way to show suggestions earlier?